# Function to read a image - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below read the image regardless the extension. But how i can remove those images in red circle?

```
...
                  const imageFileExtentions = ['svg', 'jpeg', 'png']

                  <div>
                    {imageFileExtentions.map(imageFileExtentions => (
                      <CardMedia
                        className={classes.cardMedia}
                        image={`/items/${item.ID}.${imageFileExtentions}`}
                        style={{
                          width: '50%',
                          height: '50%',
                          paddingTop: '20%'
                        }}
                        component="img"
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
...
```

[image]

Comment: Normal JavaScirpt would do `onerror="this.remove()"` Personally I would determine what it is before I display it.

Comment: how can i insert this?

Comment: Why does your inner loop call it `imageFileExtensions`? Also, open your dev tools, and look at what the actual URL is that you're making the browser look up. If it's a 404, both the console and network tab will tell you what you're doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
              <CardMedia
                className={classes.cardMedia}
                image={`/ciasbrazil/${cia.CD_CVM}.${imageFileExtentions}`}
                style={{
                  width: '50%',
                  height: '50%',
                  paddingTop: '20%'
                }}
                component="img"
                onError={e => {
                  e.target.onerror = null
                  e.target.style.display = 'none'
                }}
              />
```